# How get greatest get throughput from MQ Queue

Tags: java, performance, get, ibm-mq, mq

I am developing a java application to read data from remote IBM MQ queue and process data.

My queue receiving data with about 700-1200 TPS from MainFrame env.

I have 2 questions.

1. There are 3 method to get data

   ```
   a) MQ Java library  
   b) JNDI  
   c) JMS
   ```

   Which method is the fastest in reading data?
2. How can I increase performance of reading the queue?

   a) Read single queue with multi thread get routines
   b) Distribute data to multiple queue and read them in parallel

   Generally: how can I improve the speed of reading data from queue?

Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNDI does not provide any method to get messages from MQ queue/topic. JNDI is used for retrieving Connection and Destination configuration information from repository like LDAP or J2EE server.

Apart from Java/JMS, MQ provides APIs in C/COBOL and other languages. Based on your skills, you can choose any of the languages to develop your application.

I think it's good to start with performance reports published [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007150). These reports talk about MQ performance under different scenarios and also talk about application architecture and configuration used.